# Retrieve IMessage target instance from IServerChannelSink

Tags: c#, .net, remoting

Using .NET remoting between two processes, I'm inserting my own IServerChannel sink server-side so that I can intercept client-initiated method calls and move them to the appropriate thread on the server.  I'm currently struggling with a way to convert the `Uri` of the message into the server-object instance so that I can inspect it:

```cs
public ServerProcessing ProcessMessage(IServerChannelSinkStack sinkStack,
                                      IMessage requestMsg,
                                      ITransportHeaders requestHeaders,
                                      Stream requestStream,
                                      out IMessage responseMsg,
                                      out ITransportHeaders responseHeaders,
                                      out Stream responseStream)
{
  if (requestMsg is MethodCall methodCallMessage)
  {
    // how do I implement ConvertUriToObjectInstance to convert the Uri to a MarshallByRef instance???
    object instance = ConvertUriToObjectInstance(requestMsg.Uri);
  }
}
```

Is there a way to convert a Uri to a server-created object into the actual MarshallByRef instance?

I've looked through the `System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging` namespaces/class, both through the documentation and through reference source, but I cannot see anything related to converting the Uri back into the actual instance that it represents.  The runtime obviously has a way to do it, but is there a way that I can get it, either via an official api or by utilizing reflection?

**Note** I know that I can transition threads via something like `ContextBoundObject`, but I'm avoiding it because of its limitations - like w.r.t. generics.

Comment: Shouldn't you be converting the response (not the request)?

Comment: No; when the client invokes "MyMethodThatShouldRunOnTheUiThreadOnTheServer" I would like transition the method call onto the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [the implementation of `ChannelServices.DispatchMessage`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/remoting/channelservices.cs,674), it looks like it calls `CheckDisconnectedOrCreateWellKnownObject`, which returns a `ServerIdentity` object that contains a `TPOrObject` property which *seems* to resolve to the `MarshalByRef` instance.

So, the following reflection code can be used to retrieve the instance from the message (error checking omitted):

```
private static MethodInfo CheckDisconnectedOrCreateWellKnownObject
  = typeof(ChannelServices).GetMethod(nameof(CheckDisconnectedOrCreateWellKnownObject), BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

private static MethodInfo InstanceProperty
  = Type.GetType("System.Runtime.Remoting.Identity", true)
        .GetProperty("TPOrObject", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
        .GetGetMethod(nonPublic: true);

private static object GetObjectInstance(IMessage methodCallMessage)
{
  var wellKnownObject = CheckDisconnectedOrCreateWellKnownObject.Invoke(null, new object[] { methodCallMessage });
  return InstanceProperty.Invoke(wellKnownObject, null);
}
```

No guarantee if this is always true, however.